# Source Code stucture within Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

I need to add some source code to TFS and having never used it before i would like to get some advice on the best way to structure it.

I have one solution 'GenericLibraries'. This is a set of class library projects which could be used by any application within the business.

I have 2 other solutions 'FormsApp1', 'FormsApp2'. Both of these solutions contain dll references 
to the libraries compiled in the 'GenericLibraries' solution.

My question is how to best place this source code into TFS?

Does all the source code have to be placed into one TFS project because 'FormsApp1' and 'FormsApp2' contain references to assemblies in 'GenericLibraries' OR can i have 3 TFS projects? Or is there another standard way of doing this?

Ultimately i would like to have Continuous integration set up too, and both 'FormsApp1' , and 'FoprmsApp2' would always compile against the latest version of the assemblies in 'GenericLibraries'.

Answer (score 0):

This is a single TFS Team Project, with a common library. Consider the following structure:

```
$/MyTeamProject/Dev/GenericLibraries
$/MyTeamProject/Dev/MyProduct/FormsApp1
$/MyTeamProject/Dev/MyProduct/FormsApp2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if FormsApp1 and FormsApp2 are not part of the same product, would it still be a single TFS Project?

Comment: I don't see reason why not, a Team Project can host many different products. When different teams work on different products, then you can create a new Team Project.